# lldb 4.0 not interpreting tab key and other control characters

Tags: lldb

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04 system and installed clang-4.0 and lldb-4.0 from the designated repos:

```
deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-4.0 main
deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-4.0 main
```

For some reason, hitting the tab key enters a literal tab instead of triggering command completion, and ctrl-a and ctrl-a enter `^A` and `^E` instead of taking the cursor to the beginning or end of the line. Hitting ctrl-c gives `^C` instead of quitting the program. The arrow keys also don't work correctly. For example, left arrow gives `^[[D`.

Any ideas?

Comment: LLVM 4.0 is not yet released. Your question might be better suited for LLVM's bug tracker or mailing list.